# Laravel Sum of relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, sum, relation

I want to return the sum of "amount" from my payments table. There can be many payments for one invoice. The below "->sum('amount') does not work, it returns:

Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object.

How to return the sum of all payments for each invoice in my relation?

Invoices Model:

```
class Invoices extends Eloquent {

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payments')->sum('amount');
    }
}
```

Expenses Model:

```
class Payments extends Eloquent {

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoices');
    } 
}
```

My table "payments" holds the foreign key of my tables invoices, which is invoices_id.

Comment: You have stated that an Invoice can have many expenses, what about the inverse of the relation as you have not specified. If there is a 'one-to-many' relationship between Invoices and Expenses, shouldn't the relation be as such: Invoice HAS-MANY Expenses | Expenses BELONGS-TO Invoice. Correct me If the relation is something else.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Invoice HAS-MANY Expenses and Expenses BELONGS-TO Invoice. Is the use of a third (pivot table) useless for this I am wondering? *still learning here*

Comment: Yep, since the relation will be maintained using the id of the invoice in the expenses's table.

Comment: Thanks, going to change my tables first and see if I can find any logic in it :)

Comment: I have edited my question now with the right usage of the relationship and it's tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Invoices extends Eloquent {

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payments');
    }
}

class Payments extends Eloquent {

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoices');
    } 
}
```

In your controller

```
Invoice::with(['payments' => function($query){
   $query->sum('amount');
}])->get();
```

;

Comment: how to get that column then?

Answer (score 13):

Starting by **Laravel 8** you can simply use `withSum()` function.

```
use App\Models\Post;

$posts = Post::withSum('comments', 'votes')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_sum_votes;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Comment: Can we do this on Alias column from comment relationship ?

Comment: How to sum conditionally? like where comments has > 5 votes

Answer (score 4):

You can show this [package](https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query)

```php
$invoices = Invoices::withSum('payments:amount')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

First decide which Invoice (for example id 1)

```
$invoice = Invoices::find(1);
```

Then eager load all the corresponding payments

```
$eagerload = $invoice->payments;
```

Finally assuming you have the `amount` field in your Invoice model you can simply find the sum using the method below:

```
$totalsum = $eagerload->sum('amount');
```

Comment: This works fine for me but, in my case I need to find for all the available id, instead of just `Model::find(1);`

How can i do that ?

Comment: You should push the compute to the DB server using `Invoice::withSum('payments', 'amount')->get()` something like this

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible. we can do by model itself.

```php
class Invoices extends Eloquent {

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payments')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(payments.amount) as payment_amount')
            ->groupBy('id'); // as per our requirements.
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**
`SUM(payments.amount)`

> **payments** is tableName

> **amount** is fieldName

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to acomplish this in [here](http://developed.be/2013/08/30/laravel-4-pivot-table-example-attach-and-detach/), you can use [withPivot()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) method.

You can redefine a bit your relation to something like following

```
public function expenses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Expenses', 'invoices_expenses')
                   ->withPivot('name', 'amount', 'date');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am sure it will work, but I have just changed my tables as I was doing it wrong. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

//Model Invoices

```
class Invoices extends Eloquent {

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payments');
    }
}
```

//Model Payments

```
class Payments extends Eloquent {

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoices');
    } 
}
```

Add In your controller

```
Invoice::withSum("payments","amount")->get();
```